# onclick is not working on input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form in which I am trying to validate phone number digit should be atleast 10 digit.

```
<form name="frm" onsubmit="validate();" method="post" id="callForm">
.....
<input id="submitbtn" value="Call Me!" type="submit" /> 
</form>
<script>
function validate(){
alert("its in function");
}
</script>
```

I have also tried the same thing with :

```
<input id="submitbtn" value="Call Me!" type="submit" onclick="return validate();"/>
```

Comment: Need more clarity in question. Provide more code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
.droppbtn span{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: in fact no, with this solution the events will go through the span to the button and it will have the same effect as if the span is clickable

Comment: @raulxbox did you try my solution ?

Comment: @HajjiTarik yes it worked.. can you explain me a little how does it works

Comment: @raulxbox the thing is that, the event passes through the span to the button, before the event was stopped by the span. can you validate the answer plz :)